# Retrieve objects in array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have an array with objects like:

```
mobilephones = [[#<Phone id: 941, name: "CEO", representation_edavis_id: 172, phone_type_id: nil, number: "+12 3456789", sort_order: 13, remark: "mobile", created_at: "2015-03-05 13:27:24", updated_at: "2015-03-05 13:27:24", creator_id: nil, updater_id: nil, row_number: 941>],[#<Phone id: 946, name: "CFO", representation_edavis_id: 172, phone_type_id: nil, number: "+12 3456789", sort_order: 6, remark: "mobile", created_at: "2015-03-05 13:27:24", updated_at: "2015-03-05 13:27:24", creator_id: nil, updater_id: nil, row_number: 946>]]
```

How can I retrieve the name and number attribute of all the objects within the array?

---

I suppose normally it should work as has been suggested, but in my context, within an Rails App, I got this error message:

```
undefined method `name' for #<Array:0x421c188>
```

In the view _show.html.haml:

```
 ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `name' for #<Array:0x421c188>):
    67: - list_mobilephones(r)
    68: - @mobilephones.each do |phone|
    69:   %tr
    70:     %td= phone.name
    71:     %td= "#{phone.number} #{phone.remark}"     
    72:
```

In application_helper.rb:

```
  def list_mobilephones(rep)   
    @mobilephones = []
    rep.phones.each do |phone|     
      @mobilephones << [phone] if phone.remark == "mobile"     
      @mobilephones   
    end 
  end
```

Comment: What is your expected output? An array of hashes? Two arrays? STDOUT? Some further method?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. It's not necessary to tell us what you've added/edited in a question. We can see what you've changed, it's something that higher ranked members acquire. Instead put the information into the flow of the question, or simply delimit the new information with `---` and SO will put a horizontal rule in the question at that point.

Comment: @Anthony, it's not necessary to tell someone you've updated an answer. That's what the edit timestamp tells us.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in your specific case it would be enough, if you use `flatten`

```
@mobilephones.flatten.each do |phone|
  -# some more code
```

Depending on the usage of the variable, you could also avoid build a nested array. If you use it just in this place, try this

```
def list_mobilephones(rep)   
  @mobilephones = []
  rep.phones.each do |phone|     
    @mobilephones << phone if phone.remark == "mobile"     
    @mobilephones   
  end 
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You just loop through the array and access objects information like so:

```
mobilephones.flatten.each do |obj|
  puts "name: #{obj.name}, phone_number: #{obj.phone_number}"
end
```